# DataGrid Sorting By Any Column Only Sorts by First Column Criteria

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, gridview-sorting, xceed-datagrid

I have been scratching my head at this one for quite a while. My Xceed datagrid only sorts by AcqID and nothing else, even when I select other columns that are strings, date, and numeric. See image of date sorting below.

[image: Screen shot of wonky datagrid sorting]

My Object is pretty complex, but have no clue where to modify it to work. I have a less complex object list that seems to work just fine for sorting. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles on this... 
Setting `AutoCreateItemProperties="False"` in your `CollectionViewSource` will cause this behavior.

Comment: where you have mentioned CollectionViewSource in your question ?

Comment: I didn't know it was directly connected to CollectionViewSource